# Kotlin extending spring boot annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, annotations

With Kotlin I'm able to save defaults in a class level annotation, e.g.

```kotlin
@Profile("dev", "staging", "production")
annotation class RemoteProfile
```

I'm curious if there's a way of achieving something similar with parameter annotations - for example I'd love to be able to do something like:

```kotlin
fun someHandler(@AccountParam account: Account) {
   ...
}
```

Where underneath spring would interpret it as

```kotlin
fun someHandler(@RequestAttribute("ACCOUNT") account: Account) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: folow this https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/15/developing-spring-boot-applications-with-kotlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept you're looking for is *meta-annotation*. The reason your first example works has nothing to do with Kotlin and is a feature of Spring, where Spring actively inspects the annotation hierarchy. From [the Javadoc for `Profile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html):

> The `@Profile` annotation may be used in any of the following ways:
>
> - …
> - as a meta-annotation, for the purpose of composing custom stereotype annotations

The MVC annotations `RequestAttribute` and `RequestParam` don't support meta-annotation. You could define your own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`s to support this (it's not *terribly* complicated, and you could subclass `RequestAttributeMethodArgumentResolver`), but you can't just meta-annotate in general.

(Groovy's `AnnotationCollector` *does* support this, but it's implemented by a compile-time "unrolling", and I don't believe Kotlin has an equivalent feature.)

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for this